Generators for homology groups of projective spaces
Let $H_k(\mathbb{R}P^n; \mathbb{Z})$ be the homology groups of the real projective plane.
We know that this groups are either $\mathbb{Z}$ if $k = 0$ or if $n$ is even and $k = n$, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ if $ 0 < k < n$ and $0$ otherwise.
I am bit struggling with understanding how to get generators for this groups. For example, suppose that $\mathbb{R}P^t$ is a real projective plane of dimension $t < n$, thought of as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}P^n$. We have the inclusion map $i : \mathbb{R}P^t \rightarrow \mathbb{R} P^n$, which induces a homomorphism in homologies $i_* : H_n(\mathbb{R}P^t) \rightarrow H_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)$. Is it true that $i_*$ maps a generator to a generator?
Perhaps this question is easier over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or for a complex projective plane, but I am not sure.

This is straightforward to do using cellular homology. Recall that $\newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}}\RP^n$ admits a cell structure with one cell in each dimension $0 \leq k \leq n$ with the attaching maps alternatingly of degree 0 and 2. The cellular chain complex is thus of the form
$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
    0 \to \underbrace{C_n(\RP^n)}_{= \Z\langle e_n\rangle} \to \cdots \to \underbrace{C_2(\RP^n)}_{= \Z\langle e_2\rangle} \xrightarrow{\cdot 2}\underbrace{C_1(\RP^n)}_{= \Z\langle e_1\rangle} \xrightarrow{\cdot 0} \underbrace{C_0(\RP^n)}_{= \Z\langle e_0\rangle} \to 0
$$
where $e_k$ is the cell in dimension $k$. Taking homology, you directly see that $H_k(\RP^n)$ is generated by the class of $e_k$. In particular, this also immediately tells you that your inclusion $i_*$ maps generators to generators.
